# Changing color of only button that was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I mean I want to change CSS properties of only the button that I've clicked and at the same time set other buttons to previous color. Hope I explained my problem clear

```
for(let i = 0; i < categoryBtns.length; i++) {
    categoryBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        let attr = this.getAttribute('id');
        if(categoryBtns[i - 1].id != attr || categoryBtns[i + 1].id != attr) {
            log([i]);
            console.log('works');
            this.style.backgroundColor = '#000000';
        } else {
            log('no');
        }
    })
}
```

I have also code that shows only divs that have current category. Should I code buttons in the same time when divs are showing and hiding?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.category-item').click(function() {
        let category = $(this).attr('id');
        if(category == 'all') {
            $('.prod_item').addClass('hide');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.prod_item').removeClass('hide');
            }, 300);
        } else {
            $('.prod_item').addClass('hide');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('.' + category).removeClass('hide');
            }, 300);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I think your two blocks refer to two different questions, you should hence create a second post for it

Answer (score 1):

I hope that I understood what you want correctly

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn')

btns.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    btns.forEach(b => {
       (b.classList.contains("active"))?
       b.classList.remove("active"):true
    });
    btn.classList.add("active")
  
  });
})
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: blue;
  
}
```

```html
<button class = "btn">Click Me</button>
<button class = "btn">Click Me</button>
<button class = "btn active">Click Me</button>
<button class = "btn">Click Me</button>
<button class = "btn">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `Array.forEach()` to loop through the buttons and add/remove a styled class:

```js
const btns = document.querySelector(".buttons");
const arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(btns.children, 0);
arr.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    arr.forEach((el2) => {
      el2.classList -= "active";
    });
    el.classList.toggle("active");
  });
});
```

```css
button.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
  <button>Button 3</button>
  <button>Button 4</button>
  <button>Button 5</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class for the button clicked state, and a default color for all buttons inside divs with class `category-item`. One javascript function removes the clicked class from all buttons while the other adds it to a specific button.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.category-item input[type="button"]').click(function() {
        removeClickedClass();
        addClickedClass(this.id);
    });
  
    function removeClickedClass() {
        $('.category-item input[type="button"]').removeClass("btnColorClicked");
    }
  
    function addClickedClass(elemID) {
        let id = "#" + elemID;
        $(id).addClass("btnColorClicked");
    }
});
```

```css
.category-item input[type="button"]   {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btnColorClicked {
  background-color: #0099ff !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="category-item">
  <input type="button" class="" id="1" value="hi" />
</div>
<div class="category-item">
  <input type="button" class="" id="2" value="there" />
</div>
<div class="category-item">
  <input type="button" class="" id="3" value="hey" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer for your first block without jQuery, but you should get it.

```js
function colorizeButtons(id) {
  for (let i = 0; i < categoryBtns.length; i += 1) {
    const buttonId = categoryBtns[i].getAttribute('id');
    // Clicked button
    if (buttonId === id) {
      // Set the clicked color button
    } else {
      // Set other buttons color
    }
  }
}

for (let i = 0; i < categoryBtns.length; i++) {
  categoryBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    let attr = this.getAttribute('id');
    colorizeButtons(attr)
  });
}
```

Comment: okay, everything works as I expected but now hover of buttons defined in CSS works until I click any of them.

Comment: I don't understand what you meant. can you rephrase your sentence please ?

Answer (score 0):

here is an example with jquery btns are the list of buttons elements and when clicked they turn red if click again they turn white

```
$(btns).on("click",function(){
    if(!this.clicked){
        this.clicked = true;
        $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    }
    else{
       this.clicked = false;
       $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    }
});
```